# Static Linking Problem in Qt with SQLite

Tags: c++, qt, static

I'm having a static linking problem in my C++ app. I'm hoping you can help. Code for header and source below.

```
#ifndef PRACTICARDSDB_H
#define PRACTICARDSDB_H
#include "cardset.h"
#include "card.h"
#include "filter.h"

class PractiCardsDB
{
public:
    PractiCardsDB();
    static void resetAll();
    static void resetDates();
    static CardSet getCardSet();
    static CardSet getCardSet(Filter filter);
    static void addCard(Card card);
    static void editCard(Card card);
    static void deleteCard(Card card);
    static bool createConnection();

};

#endif // PRACTICARDSDB_H
```

Above is the header file and below is the source file.

```
#include "practicardsdb.h"
#include <QtSql/QSqlDatabase>
#include <QMessageBox>

PractiCardsDB::PractiCardsDB() {}
static bool PractiCardsDB::createConnection()
{
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setDatabaseName("EnglishSpanish");
    if (!db.open())
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The error I receive is: cannot declare member function 'static bool PractiCardsDB::createConnection()' to have static linkage. Any help?

I'm using Qt 4.7 with C++ inside Qt Creator if it helps.

Comment: Ok. I just figured out how to actually see the full compile error. It looks like I was missing the references to the SQL libraries. I saw another SO question earlier mentioning this so I added QT += sql in the .pro file and it is working now. Thanks all. Sorry for the Qt Newbie problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you define a `static` member function separately from the declaration, you do not have to use the `static` modifier.

```
bool PractiCardsDB::createConnection()
{
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setDatabaseName("EnglishSpanish");
    if (!db.open())
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Also do you really mean to make every single function of your class `static`? Your class represents a database of sorts for `Card` objects, so I think you'd want to actually store member data with the class itself?

Even in that snippet above, you create a `QSqlDatabase` object, but `db`'s existence is only the extent of the `createConnection()` function.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I removed the extra static and now have a new error: :: error: collect2: ld returned 1 exit status. I am actually trying to convert this from C# to C++ with Qt, so I'm really don't mind how to do it. Right now I have my CardSet class controlling all the database access so the DB mirrors what it is in the CardSet so static worked well for my C# version.

Comment: @Awaken - `ld returned 1 exit status` messages usually mean you have missing symbols in compilation. Are you linking in the Qt libraries you have to? Are you using a qmake .pro file?

Answer (score 2):

Remove `static` decleration from your `cpp` file, it should only be in the `header` file. Like:

```
bool PractiCardsDB::createConnection()
{
 ....
}
```

Comment: Removed extra static. New error: :: error: collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Post the full error, you are missing some libraries it seems.

Comment: Yep. I needed to add sql to my project.